# Confetti in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get my code to randomly place 50 randomly colored circles, or "confetti", within a box. So far all that appears is one black circle in the upper left corner of the box.

```js
"use strict";

window.onload = function() {
    document.onclick = create;
};

function trim(data) {
    var start;
    var whitespace;
    var end;
    var result;

    if (typeof data === "string") {
        whitespace = " \n\r\t\f";
        start = 0;
    } else {
        result = data;
    }

    while ((start < data.length) && (whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(start)))) {
        start = start + 1;
    };
    end = data.length - 1;

    while ((end >= 0) && (whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(end)))) {
        end = end - 1;
    };

    if (end < start) {
        result = "";
    } else {
        result = data.substring(1 + start, end);
    }
    return result;
};


function getRandomInteger(upperLimit) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperLimit + 1));
};

function getRandomRGB() {
    var blue;
    var green;
    var red;
    red = getRandomInteger(255);
    blue = getRandomInteger(255);
    green = getRandomInteger(255);
    return "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
};

function createHTMLElement(elementType, id, classInfo, content) {
    if (elementType === null) {
        elementType = "";
    };

    trim(elementType);

    if (id === null) {
        id = "";
    }

    trim(id);

    if (id.length > 0) {
        id = " " + "id=" + '"' + id + '"' + " ";
    };

    if (classInfo === null) {
        classInfo = "";
    }

    trim(classInfo);

    if (classInfo.length > 0) {
        classInfo = " " + "class=" + '"' + classInfo + '"';
    }

    if (content === null) {
        content = "";
    };

    trim(content);

    return '<' + elementType +
        id + classInfo +
        '>' + content +
        '</' + elementType + '>';
};

function createConfetti(containerId, howMany) {
    var element;
    var i;
    var idPrefix;
    var result;


    result = "";
    idPrefix = "circles";
    i = 0;
    element = document.getElementById(idPrefix + i);
    while (i < howMany) {
        result = result + createHTMLElement("span", idPrefix + i, "confetti", "&bull;");
        i = i + 1;
    } //while

    document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML = result;


    while (i < howMany) {
        document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.color = getRandomRGB();
        document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.top = getRandomInteger(offsetHeight - 4) + "px";
        document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.left = getRandomInteger(offsetWidth - 4) + "px";
        i = i + 1;
    } //while
};

function create() {
    createConfetti("container", 50);
};
```

```css
{
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 10em;
  line-height: .9em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 30em;
}
.confetti {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Confetti Part 1</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id=container></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you inspect, you'll notice that there's not only one circle being drawn - there's 50 black circles being drawn, all in the top left on top of each other. That suggests maybe there's something wrong with how you're generating numbers? It also looks like you're referring to variables called offsetHeight and offsetWidth that aren't ever created.

Comment: I think a `for` loop would be better suited for your needs than a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

You use the same variable (i) for both loops. But you don't reset i back to zero. Second, you just reference offsetHeight and offsetWidth. I'm assuming you mean the container's width and height? So your updated code should look like:

```
  i=0;
  while (i < howMany) {
    document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.color = getRandomRGB();
    document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.top = getRandomInteger(document.getElementById(containerId).offsetHeight - 4) + "px";
    document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.left = getRandomInteger(document.getElementById(containerId).offsetWidth - 4) + "px";
    i = i + 1;
  } //while
```

```js
"use strict";

window.onload = function() {
  document.onclick = create;
};

function trim(data) {
  var start;
  var whitespace;
  var end;
  var result;

  if (typeof data === "string") {
    whitespace = " \n\r\t\f";
    start = 0;
  } else {
    result = data;
  }

  while ((start < data.length) && (whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(start)))) {
    start = start + 1;
  };
  end = data.length - 1;

  while ((end >= 0) && (whitespace.indexOf(data.charAt(end)))) {
    end = end - 1;
  };

  if (end < start) {
    result = "";
  } else {
    result = data.substring(1 + start, end);
  }
  return result;
};


function getRandomInteger(upperLimit) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperLimit + 1));
};

function getRandomRGB() {
  var blue;
  var green;
  var red;
  red = getRandomInteger(255);
  blue = getRandomInteger(255);
  green = getRandomInteger(255);
  return "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
};

function createHTMLElement(elementType, id, classInfo, content) {
  if (elementType === null) {
    elementType = "";
  };

  trim(elementType);

  if (id === null) {
    id = "";
  }

  trim(id);

  if (id.length > 0) {
    id = " " + "id=" + '"' + id + '"' + " ";
  };

  if (classInfo === null) {
    classInfo = "";
  }

  trim(classInfo);

  if (classInfo.length > 0) {
    classInfo = " " + "class=" + '"' + classInfo + '"';
  }

  if (content === null) {
    content = "";
  };

  trim(content);

  return '<' + elementType +
    id + classInfo +
    '>' + content +
    '</' + elementType + '>';
};

function createConfetti(containerId, howMany) {
  var element;
  var i;
  var idPrefix;
  var result;


  result = "";
  idPrefix = "circles";
  i = 0;
  element = document.getElementById(idPrefix + i);
  while (i < howMany) {
    result = result + createHTMLElement("span", idPrefix + i, "confetti", "&bull;");
    i = i + 1;
  } //while

  document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML = result;

  i=0;
  while (i < howMany) {
    document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.color = getRandomRGB();
    document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.top = getRandomInteger(document.getElementById(containerId).offsetHeight - 4) + "px";
    document.getElementById(idPrefix + i).style.left = getRandomInteger(document.getElementById(containerId).offsetWidth - 4) + "px";
    i = i + 1;
  } //while
};

function create() {
  createConfetti("container", 50);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Confetti Part 1</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <script src="ConfettiPart1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    {
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
      font-size: 12pt;
    }
    #container {
      border: 2px solid black;
      height: 10em;
      line-height: .9em;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      position: relative;
      width: 30em;
    }
    .confetti {
      font-size: 3em;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id=container></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

fouund something

```
idPrefix = "circles";
    i      = 0;
    element = document.getElementById( idPrefix+i );
    while( i < howMany )
    {
    result=result+createHTMLElement("span", idPrefix+i, "confetti", "&bull;");
    i = i+1;
    }//while
    document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML=result;
```

at this point, i = 50, and won´t enter next loop

```
    while( i < howMany )
    {
```